# Using QGIS or GRASS API in custom application

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geojson, software-recommendations, dxf

I've already read [in this link](http://Use%20QGIS%20plugins%20in%20custom%20standalone%20application%20[duplicate]) that is not possibile to use QGIS or other GIS application API (GRASS, ArcGIS) without rebuild all libraries into my custom code. First I would like to know if that corresponds to the truth or if there is a way to integrate these APIs without the whole application. What I would like to do is to convert a DXF file into a GeoJSON and use it for my application. A possibile workaround is install the server version of QGIS somewhere (I'm considering to add it to my application's docker container) and create a Python application that can leverage QGIS API previously installed.

Is there any other library for this type of conversion?

Comment: Your link path is corrupt (pasted text, not URL).

Comment: Yon don't need QGIS, GRASS GIS or ArcGIS, for that, simply use the Python geospatial modules (OGR, Fiona, GeoPandas, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply; you man this kind of api? http://geopandas.org/io.html?highlight=geojson ?PS: sorry for the link i'll try to find it again. Could i assume that the library could also provide srs system information and provide system reference conversion to obtain a correct information that can i overlap to a map (for example google map or open street map)?

Comment: is there any kind of tutorial that explains how to programmatically georeference a non-georeferenced dxf file?